# Adding CSS to an Embedded Yammer

Tags: css, sharepoint, yammer, sharepoint-online

```
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:800px;width:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

yam.connect.embedFeed({
  "config": {
    "use_sso": false,
    "header": false,
    "footer": false,
    "showOpenGraphPreview": false,
    "defaultToCanonical": false,
    "hideNetworkName": false,
    "defaultGroupId": 8430003
  },
  "container": "#embedded-feed"
});

</script>
```

How would I insert CSS into it in order to change the background color of the embedded yammer?

```
<style>
#embedded-feed { background-color: orange; }
</style>
```

If I use the above CSS turns it orange, and the immediately reverses.

[image]

Comment: just add CSS to the container, something like `#embedded-feed { background-color: orange; }` should work.

Comment: It looked like it would work and then reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded content is inside an `iframe` that got a white background. I'm afraid you cannot change it.

You can sort of manipulate it in a hacky way, by using a pseudo element (`::after`) on top of the container (`#embedded-feed`), which has a **background** and a **blend mode**:

```css
#embedded-feed {
  position: relative;
}

#embedded-feed::after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0;
  background: orange;
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:400px;width:500px;"></div>
<script>
    yam.connect.embedFeed({
        container: '#embedded-feed',
        network: 'fourleaf.com',
        feedType: 'group',                // can be 'group', 'topic', or 'user'    
        feedId: '123',                     // feed ID from the instructions above
        config: {
             defaultGroupId: 3257958      // specify default group id to post to 
        }
    });    
</script>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/40faxryw/

Be careful, this is **experimental** and has limited browser support as of now (FF32, Chrome 41+, Safari 8+, Opera, No IE).

You can play around with different options, colors and/or opacity:

[image: css mix blend mode background pseudo element]

Cannot think of another solution that does not involve CORS.

- [MDN - CSS mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)
- [Can I use... mix-blend-mode](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode)

Comment: Customisation of Yammer Embed is unsupported. It is not a good idea to do this in a customer or production environment because it can result in a poor experience and problems getting support.